# Discord.py send a dm to a user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I made a dm command for my bot which works well but I can't dm a user with a space in user name. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    message = message or "Message from bot owner"
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message from bot owner", description=message, color = 0)
    await user.send(embed = embed)
```

When I was trying to dm a user with a space for example: `=dm Special user#1234` My terminal says that user Special is not found.

Comment: Are you familiar with a user ID instead?

Comment: You can mention the user and it will also work

Comment: Yeah, ikr but I want to dm user beyond my server @ŁukaszKwieciński.

Comment: Yes but I want to do that without ID @Dominik.

Comment: Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: You can just DM user on your server/servers where the bot is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm(ctx, user, *, message=None):
    if message is None:
        await ctx.send("You need to specify the message to send!")
        return
    user = client.fetch_user(user)
    await user.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Message from bot owner", description=message, color = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should have a separate way to define the `message` variable, since the `member` variable might take in spaces. Here is how I would define the function:

```
@commands.command()
async def dm(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send('Enter a message to DM in the chat...')
    msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    await member.send(msg.content)
```